# Best way to classify/mark babel generated files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using IntelliJ with Gulp (with the babel and sourecemap plugins) to help me transpile my source ES6 to ES5. What is the best way to mark these generated files?

They are being sent into a seperate `dist` folder but I want them to behave in the following way:

1. I don't want them to show up in usage/code search
2. I want their changes to be detected by the integrated source control

I have tagged them as `excluded` but I read in IntelliJ's docs that this will prevent the folder from being watched for changes. Anyone have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding the `dist` folder via `Mark directory as/Excluded` is the right way to go: files in excluded folders are not indexed/show up in usage/code search, but they can be version controlled, so both your requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: They can be version controlled, but I've noticed that when Gulp compiles this files, it sometimes requires me to actually physically go and click on the compiled file for it to show up as having changes against master. I assume this isn't intended to work this way? It can also be very dangerous because I could commit my changes to the source and the compiled version could be out of date.

Comment: Is there some way to instruct gulp to notify IntelliJ of changes? Because this would also become an issue if I made edits to these source files outside of chrome (say in Chrome Dev tools or on the command line)

Comment: do you run Gulp from within Idea, using Gulp integration, or externally? In the latter case,   file system changes have to be synchronized manually (by moving focus from and then back to Idea or by performing File/Synchronize). Unfortunately this is also the case when using Gulp from Idea, but this issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14873) is fixed in Idea 15

Comment: oh wow, thanks so much! I'm coincidentally running the EAP already for 15, so I guess I'll just be patient as I see it's in the pipeline.